# How to use v-model value in components

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vue-component

I created a vue component that uses v-model value:

```
Vue.component('dynamic-component', {
    props: ['message'],
    template: '<p>The message: {{message}}</p>'
});
```

This is my vue instance

```
var vm = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: function() {
        return {message: ''}
    },
});
```

This is the Html:

```
<div id="app">
        <textarea v-model="message"  placeholder="add multiple lines"></textarea>
 <p>
 <dynamic-component v-show="message"></dynamic-component>
 </p>
</div>
```

The `{{message}}` value doesn't appear in the placed template. What should I do?

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mp8m0ben/17/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to actually pass the message into that component, like this:

```
<div id="app">
  <textarea v-model="message" placeholder="add multiple lines"></textarea>
  <p>
    <dynamic-component :message="message" v-show="message"></dynamic-component>
  </p>
</div>
```

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/qf0cjpak/).